# how to add the string to parameters

Tags: ios, swift4

I want to add the parameters in type of string. I am using following method
to adding the data.

```
 let param = ["user_id": "5","start_date": start,"end_date" : end,"start_time": start_Time,"end_time":end_Time,"departure_time":departure_Time,"payment_email":paymentEmailTextField.text!,"tripData":String1 ,"image": imageData] as [String : Any]
```

I add to the "tripData" value by String1

```
var String1 = """
{
"trip_types":"\(preferedSelectString)",
"attractions": \(addAttractionArray),
"description": "\(self.tripDescriptionTextFiled.text!)",
"type": "\(search_type)",
"cost" : "\(self.priceperPersonTextField.text!)",
"location": "\(self.countryLabel.text!)",
"title": "\(self.tittletripTextField.text!)",
"max_persons": "\(self.peopleCountLabel.text!)",
"advance": "\(self.loadingDepositeTextField.text!)",
"address": "\(self.googleAddressTextField.text!)",
"city": "\(self.cityLabel.text!)",
"state": "\(self.state)",
"country": "\(self.countryLabel.text!)",
"amenities": "\(self.amenitiesString)"
}
"""
```

just printed my console the string1 display the data

```
{
"trip_types":"5",
"attractions": [],
"description": "des",
"type": "0",
"cost" : "100",
"location": "India",
"title": "tittle",
"max_persons": "3",
"advance": "50",
"address": "Vadapalani",
"city": "Chennai",
"state": "Tamil Nadu",
"country": "India",
"amenities": "wifi"
}
```

But i print the param value does not properly display the data

```
["tripData": "{\n\"trip_types\":\"5\",\n\"attractions\": [],\n\"description\": \"des\",\n\"type\": \"0\",\n\"cost\" : \"100\",\n\"location\": \"India\",\n\"title\": \"tittle\",\n\"max_persons\": \"3\",\n\"advance\": \"50\",\n\"address\": \"Vadapalani\",\n\"city\": \"Chennai\",\n\"state\": \"Tamil Nadu\",\n\"country\": \"India\",\n\"amenities\": \"wi\"\n}", "start_time": "11:00:00", "image": [473044 bytes], "end_time": "10:00:00", "user_id": "5", "payment_email": "add@gmail.com", "start_date": "2018-03-20", "end_date": "2018-03-20", "departure_time": "10:00:00"]
```

In param data \n\",\" these values are added Automatically.so Json values are not added in parameters.

i want to display the data following type

```
["tripData": {"trip_types":"1,2,3", "attractions":["something","somecontent"], "description":"Come with me to see","type":"1","cost":"120", "location":"Australia","title":"OLD TOWN CASTLE TOUR", "max_persons":"2","advance":"120", "address":"something","city":"chennai","state":"Tamilnadu","country":"", "amenities":"wifi,photo"},"start_time": "11:00:00", "image": [473044 bytes], "end_time": "10:00:00", "user_id": "5", "payment_email": "add@gmail.com", "start_date": "2018-03-20", "end_date": "2018-03-20", "departure_time": "10:00:00"]
```

tripData value is String Format.
"tripData" have a separate string in Type(String1). how to sent the parameters with in the string. Please Help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSONEncoder` to convert JSON data to `String`

```
    let param = ["user_id": "5"]
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    if let jsonData = try? encoder.encode(param) {
        if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
            print(jsonString)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response sir. i using your method following error will be displayed.  "Thread 1: Fatal error: Dictionary<String, Any> does not conform to Encodable because Any does not conform to Encodable."

Comment: keys and values must implement [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types). Strings, Ints, and Doubles are already Codable, but if you have other type then have to implement.

Answer (score 0):

```
param["tripData": "{\n\"trip_types\":\"5\",\n\"attractions\": [],\n\"description\": \"des\",\n\"type\": \"0\",\n\"cost\" : \"100\",\n\"location\": \"India\",\n\"title\": \"tittle\",\n\"max_persons\": \"3\",\n\"advance\": \"50\",\n\"address\": \"Vadapalani\",\n\"city\": \"Chennai\",\n\"state\": \"Tamil Nadu\",\n\"country\": \"India\",\n\"amenities\": \"wi\"\n}", "start_time": "11:00:00", "image": [473044 bytes], "end_time": "10:00:00", "user_id": "5", "payment_email": "add@gmail.com", "start_date": "2018-03-20", "end_date": "2018-03-20", "departure_time": "10:00:00"]
```

Here you are adding only 1 key-Value of type [String:String]. Before setting the value for key "tripData" make sure you have converted the JSON string into the Dictionary format.
You haven't converted the JSON string into Dictionary. that's why it is considering it as a string.
Make sure you are converting the String into Dictionary before parsing.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir. i will try sir.